# Solution of stochastic differnetial equation adapted?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, filtrations

Consider the following stochastic differential equation:

$$dY_t = Z_t dW_t$$ and terminal condition $Y_T = b,$ for which holds:  $E[|b|^2] < \infty$
Furthermore b is adapted to the filtration generated by the Browian motion only at terminal time $T$.

$Z_t$ is a predictable square integrable process. So the right hand side $Z_t dW_t$ is martingale.

Why is the solution $Y_t$ adapted to the underlying filtration
If I rewrite the equation, I get: $$Y_t = Y_T - \int_t^T Z_s dW_s =  b - \int_t^T Z_s dW_s $$.

Since $b$ is only mb w.r.t to terminal time $T$, $Y_t$ cannot be adapted.

Where did I do a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that $b$ and $\int_t^T Z_s dW_s$ are not $\mathcal F_t$ measurable, $b - \int_t^T Z_s dW_s$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable.  That's because $$b - \int_t^T Z_s dW_s = Y_T - \int_t^T Z_s dW_s = \int_0^TZ_s dW_s - \int_t^T Z_s dW_s = \int_0^t Z_s dW_s.$$

If you're confused about why there is a solution to this backwards stochastic differential equation, note that $Y_t := \mathbb{E}[b|\mathcal F_t]$ is a martingale satisfying $Y_T = b$, so by the martingale representation theorem there exists an adapted process $Z$ such that $dY_t = Z_t dW_t$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the solution to $dY_t =Z_t dW_t$ is $Y_t =E[b| F_t]$. This is obviously an adpated solution.

Comment: How do you see, that $Y_T =  \int_{0}^T Z_t dW_t$

Comment: @Sarah Generally the solution to a backwards stochastic differential equation like this is considered to be the _pair_ (Y,Z), such that $dY_t = Z_t dW_t$ and $Y_T = b$, rather than just $Y_t = E[b|\mathcal F_t]$.  The second comment is actually a mistake in my post - we should have $Y_T = Y_0 + \int_0^T Z_s dW_s$, which is just the meaning of the notation $dY_t = Z_t dW_t$.

Comment: So $Z$ should make $Y$ adapted? But is $Y$ some kind of redundant since it is given in terms of $Z$?

Comment: But if I have $Y_T = Y_0 + \int_{0}^T  Z_s dW_s$, how can I see  if plug that in your solution that $Y_0  + \int_0^t Z_s dW_s$ is adaped?

Comment: Sure, I guess $Y$ is kind of redundant and you could instead of thinking of solving for $Z$ such that $b-\int_0^T Z_s dW_s$ is a constant, but that isn't how it's normally done.  For your other question, $Y_0$ is a constant and $\int_0^t Z_s dW_s$ is adapted by construction of the stochastic integral, so $Y_0 + \int_0^t Z_s dW_s$ is adapted.

Comment: Sorry. I do not get it. Why should $Y_0 $ be constant?

Comment: Because the notation $dY_t = Z_t dW_t$ means $Y_t = Y_0 + \int_0^t Z_s dW_s$ for some $Y_0 \in \mathcal F_0$.  Since the Brownian filtration is trivial at time $0$, we must have $Y_0$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. I appreciate your help:)